# Flight booked with AirNZ reward dollars, can I use my SA Gold (different loyalty program) to get extra baggage?

Tags: luggage, loyalty-programs, star-alliance

I have two loyalty programmes, well actually I used to have AirNZ but then switched to SA KrisFlyer as my primary. My AirNZ is just standard level, but my SA KrisFlyer is Gold.

I finally used my AirNZ dollars waiting to be used on a AKL>SIN flight, however as that loyalty card is only standard it doesn't come with any extra baggage privileges.

Does anyone know if I can just show my SA KrisFlyer Gold at check in to give me an extra checked bag for free? Or will the fact that the loyalty programme that is logged against the flight isn't Gold mess that up?

Comment: This is the closest information that I found: http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/united-airlines-mileageplus/1480009-gold-benefits-tk-elite-ua-award-flight-booking.html - there is a good chance. I would suggest that you call AirNZ up to ask your SA frequent flyer number to be added to the booking and listen to what they replay.

Comment: Here is another thread at flyertalk: http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/singapore-airlines-krisflyer/1746353-new-star-alliance-gold.html

Comment: Also see *[Can I switch OneWorld airline loyalty schemes and retain my benefits?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/60864)*

Answer (score 1):

I can't say for sure about Air NZ, but I have done this with Delta, including the award tickets. You can call them and ask them to put a different Frequent Flier number on your ticket, and then the eligibility for benefits would be defined by this number. Unless AirNZ has a requirement that you should only use your AirNZ FF# on award ticket (Delta and Alaska do not), this should be easy.

You may need to do this in advance; at least with Delta if you already got a free upgrade (which can happen up to 5 days before the flight depending on your status), they will not be able to remove the FF# from the ticket.

Note that many benefits (such as access to priority checkin, lounge and priority boarding) you can get even without having your FF number on a ticket - you just need to show your frequent flier card. Used this a lot last year, when I flew Delta while parking miles on Alaska. However free luggage allowance (and complimentary upgrades) are generally tied up to having FF# on a ticket.

Answer (score 0):

According to NZ's baggage rules, no.  You can only get Star Gold benefits, which includes an extra bag, when the itinerary includes 2 or more Star Alliance carriers.

If you are flying non-stop on NZ, you do not meet this requirement.

[NZ Baggage Allowances](https://www.airnewzealand.co.nz/checked-in-baggage)

Comment: Downvote?  Really?  Source?  Totally unwarranted.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I don't think you have answered the question asked.

Comment: @GeorgeY.  That answer is directly from the NZ web site describing Star baggage allowances.

Comment: So you're sure he's taking a direct flight? There are connecting AKL-SIN flights on AirNZ.

Comment: @GeorgeY. "on a AKL>SIN flight" is not particularly ambiguous.  NZ flies this route and booking anything else as an award would be quite challenging.  So, yes, I am more than reasonably sure.

Comment: ALK-SIN could be flown with AirNZ via a connecting flight. And AirNZ is a Star Alliance member, so even using your link the free allowance would apply.

Comment: @GeorgeY. The OP gives no indication this is a connecting itinerary.  Sure he could have booked it as a RTW via LAX/LHR/FRA/NRT.  Such speculation would make every question unanswerable.

Comment: No need to make ridiculous arguments. Please check Kayak - plenty of AirNZ itineraries AKL-SIN connect in Christchurch, NZ.

Comment: @GeorgeY. I'm making ridiculous arguments.  I'm answering based on the information provided by the OP which is a flight from AKL to SIN.  There is no indication of a connection or multi-carrier itinerary.  That would be a significant detail to forget to add.  Presumably, the flight is booked with NZ since OP states Airpoints is the program it's associated with.

Comment: Well, there is NO indication of it being direct itinerary either. And since it is an award ticket, the typical "direct is better" logic doesn't always apply. And this detail is only significant when you know about it.